# Intellij not recognizing java 8 maven project automatic module name

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-11, java-module

I'm trying to add multiple java 8 maven dependencies to a java 11 maven project in intellij.  I've added the automatic module name to the java 8 pom like so where `com.robert.package8` is the package name.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Automatic-Module-Name>com.robert.package8</Automatic-Module-Name>
            </manifestEntries>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In the java 11 project I've added the package as a dependency in the pom and added it as a maven project in intellij setting the sdk to java 8 for the `package8` project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.robert</groupId>
    <artifactId>package8</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

However when importing packages in the java 11 project, I get the error

> Package com.robert.package8 is declared in the unnamed module but module com.robert.package11 does not read it

and requiring it in my module-info.java givens a `Module not found` error

Is there something that I'm missing or doing incorrectly?  The package8 project is added via pom and the directory contains project files and isn't just a jar.

Comment: Can you build the project by Maven from command line?

Answer (score 1):

Removing or setting the `addClassPath` to `false` would help you here.

```
<archive>
    <manifestEntries>
        <Automatic-Module-Name>com.robert.package8</Automatic-Module-Name>
    </manifestEntries>
</archive>
```

The above is sufficient for the module to be used in the modulepath and using `Automatic-Module-Name` would help recognize your Jar as a java module with the specified name.

Comment: I would recommend understanding the [concept of the unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module).